# Override path resolve for css bundling in webpack

Tags: javascript, css, sass, webpack

Based on the https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit repo which uses Webpack, I'm trying to implement a build process that overwrites *.scss files of the standard build with files from another folder.

```
/src
    /styles
        core.scss
        _colors.scss
        _common.scss
    /custom-styles
        /skin-1
            /styles
                _colors.scss
```

`core.scss` in this example does `@import 'colors'` (as seen below) which loads the `/src/styles/_colors.scss` file.

core.scss:

```
:global {
    @import 'colors';
}
```

I now want to configure Webpack to first check the `/custom-styles/skin-1` folder for the file, and then only if no file was found at the custom location, to fallback to the standard path resolve.

So with the override active:

- `@import 'colors'` would resolve the file `/src/custom-styles/skin-1/styles/_colors.scss`
- `@import 'common'` would resolve the file `/src/styles/_common.scss` but first checked if `/src/custom-styles/skin-1/styles/_common.scss` is available

There is a webpack plugin called `path-override-webpack-plugin` which can successfully do that for `*.js` files (https://github.com/jamiehill/path-override-webpack-plugin). But unfortunately it does not override the paths used with `@import` inside the `*.scss` files.

How is this behavior achievable?